# How to restore state of android fragment where recyclerView has selected item

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a fragment where i used recyclerview and recyler items can be select/unselect . But problem is that when i move to other fragment and back to the same fragment then selected data lost .

How can i get the fragment as like previous condition where selected items will be at selected condition .

Comment: Override `onSaveInstanceState` and/or `onPause`, `onResume` and save the relevant data there.

Comment: I think it is because you are not saving data for selected item. Your fragment will be created again when you switch back. Now if you have not stored selected item. It will show you default values or past data.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SaveInstanceState lets check one sample below

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    // These variable are destroyed along with Activity
    private int someVarA;
    private String someVarB;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("someVarA", someVarA);
        outState.putString("someVarB", someVarB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        someVarA = savedInstanceState.getInt("someVarA");
        someVarB = savedInstanceState.getString("someVarB");
    }

}
```

There is no onRestoreInstanceState method inside Fragment.
For Fragment, there is some special case that is different from Activity and I think that you need to know about it. Once Fragment is returned from backstack, its View would be destroyed and recreated.